# ViewModelProviders failing instantation because "of" cannot be resolved

Tags: android, mvvm

Im experimenting with view models but, came across an odd error the compiler says it doesn't recognize "of". I already have the the dependency imported in my build.gradle and sycned like so

```
 def ver = "1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$ver"
```

I made sure it is imported correctly in my activity and instantated. Not sure what to do

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;


 //private BattleRhythmViewModel battleModel;
   battleModel = new ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BattleRhythmViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BattleRhythmViewModel.class)`

`of` is a static method. When you call `new ViewModelProviders.of(this)`, you are tying to create a new instance of `ViewModelProviders` using constructor, but you never called the constructor using `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `this` is an instance of `activity` or `fragments`, Secondly, update the [latest version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle) of `ViewModel` library, Thirdly **`new`** keyword is unnecessary since you will not create an instance of `ViewModel` manually it is provided to you.

Answer (score 0):

for those that other answers not works for them, make sure that you are using `ViewModelProviders` instead of `ViewModelProvider`